# Jmeter close connection before my test finish

Tags: http, jmeter

I use jmeter HTTP Sampler to test a sequence of HTTP requests and choosed "Use KeepAlive". But a few threads Jmeter closed connection with TCP FIN before all 
requests send out.
[image]

As the picture shown, 172.19.0.101 is Jmeter,172.19.0.111 is the server. The rest of requests can be only send in a new connection and they are out of session.

Comment: let us know the server which you are using and what are the values configured for keep-alive timeout, connectionTimeout and max number of requests that can be sent on a Persistent Connection

Comment: Appreciate for your helping. I checked the configuration, neither timeout nor 'max' Parameter set. And the Jmeter client disconnect initiative，not the Apache server. So I thought may be problem on Jmeter or client machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be of two reasons:

**First reason - timeout**

whether **timeout** is reached (default value is 60 seconds, and configurable. If not configured, it uses the connectionTimeout parameter value in tomcat server).

> the default connection timeout of Apache httpd 1.3 and 2.0 is as
>   little as 15 seconds and just 5 seconds for Apache httpd 2.2 and
>   above

I observed that the request got the response after 10 seconds (15 -> 29 seconds) before sending FIN signal to terminate the connection.

References:

1. https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-thomson-hybi-http-timeout-01.html#p-timeout
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection
3. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html

**Second reason -  'max' Parameter**

May be it reached the number of requests that can be sent on a single Persistent Connetion.

1. https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-thomson-hybi-http-timeout-01.html#p-max

Set Implementation in HTTP Samplers to HTTPClient4 and try.

From JMeter HTTP Sampler documentation.

> JMeter sets the Connection: keep-alive header. This does not work properly with the default HTTP implementation, as connection re-use is not under user-control. It does work with the Apache HttpComponents HttpClient implementations.

Comment: check the value configured for keepalive timeout  "#httpclient4.idletimeout=0" in JMeter.properties file. also connectionTimeout value "#httpclient.timeout=0". edited the answer

Comment: Thanks for your helping. The parameter seem to be useful, some connections can be keep alived. But not all the connections are OK, Jmeter client  still disconnect initiative ocassionally before the test finishes. I will try to get more information.

Comment: focus on both server and client side "Keep-Alive" headers and analyse what both are agreed upon to keep the persistent connection.

Comment: try tweaking  "#httpclient4.time_to_live=2000" in jmeter.properties

Answer (score 0):

Find the jmeter.properties file in jmeter5.4.1, which describes the parameters during iteration:

```
# Reset HTTP State when starting a new Thread Group iteration which means:
# true means next iteration is associated to a new user
# false means next iteration is associated to same user
# true involves:
# - Closing opened connection
# - resetting SSL State
#httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration=true
```

set

```
httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration=false
```